# Removing Japanese text between two vertical bars using regex and notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text like this

```
English text||Arabic text||Japanese text||Arabic text||numbers
```

I tried using `(\|\|\p{Han}\p{Hiragana}\p{Katakana}\|\|)` but I'm getting "invalid Regular Expression" error message in notepad++, although it's right as I tested it in [This regex tester](http://regex101.com/), Plus this will only look at the Japanese text with Katakana after Hiragana after Kanji, how can I make it look an the Japanese text without that order?

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ **does not support** **`\p`** modifier, try **`\p{Letter}`** (should match any letter in any language) and you will see no match.

You can use some other application, e.g. a very good one is **EditPad**.

Answer (score 0):

I figured what's the main problem, I have to `[\p{Han}\p{Hiragana}\p{Katakana}]` if I don't want it in a specific order, so all what I had to do is find: `\|\|([\p{Han}\p{Hiragana}\p{Katakana}]*?)\|\|` and replace it with `||`.

Of course Notepad++ didn't work, So I used **EditPad** as *NikitOn* suggested